# Date format with all capital letters

Tags: php

The PHP code below returns dates in this format:

> July 27, 2010     7:36 pm

How could I make it return dates with capital letters?  Here's what I want;

> JULY 27, 2010     7:36 PM

Thanks in advance,

John

The PHP code:

```
format('F j, Y &\nb\sp &\nb\sp g:i a')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [strtoupper()](http://au.php.net/strtoupper) function converts all the characters in a string to uppercase. You can use it in the following way:

```
strtoupper(format('F j, Y &\nb\sp &\nb\sp g:i a'));
```

If you have having problems with the spaces, remember that it's `&nbsp;`. Inserting capitals there might not work either. You could try the following:

```
strtoupper(format('F j, Y'))."&nbsp;&nbsp;".strtoupper(format('g:i a'));
```

Comment: Thanks... but it also seems to make the PHP echo out the &\nb\sp rather than leaving it as a space.